# Gantt schedule calendar one on top of the other

Tags: javascript, calendar, frontend, schedule

I'm using a library to use a Gantt, but I'm not able to add it to Gantts on other lines, they're on top of each other. I would like to know if anyone knows how to solve this, as in the documentation below this is not very clear. Below is a screenshot of what is happening.[image]

https://gantt-schedule-timeline-calendar.neuronet.io/

Answer (score 0):

The overflow may be a result of the opacity of the items not being zero.
Using the same lib with the same problem I just set the opacity of the gantt row item to 1 and worked well for me:

```css
.gantt-schedule-timeline-calendar__chart-timeline-items-row-item {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```